# sqlite insert into table with NULL foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have the following tables: (notice that SUPP may be NULL)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A 
(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS B 
(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS C 
(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS D 
(
  SID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  DID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SUPP INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (SID, DID),
  FOREIGN KEY (SID) REFERENCES A (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES B (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (SUPP) REFERENCES C (ID)
);
```

Assuming table A contains ID=2 and table B contains ID=5.
I want to perform the following insert:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO D VALUES (2,5,NULL);
```

However I get the following error:

> Foreign key mismatch - D referencing C (INSERT INTO "main"."D" ...

I'm assuming the issue stems from the NULL foreign key but I don't know what I did wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/24vNe4tmPcn1uAnfppU6aG/0

Comment: Remove the last `,` from `FOREIGN KEY (SUPP) REFERENCES C (ID),`

Comment: But i need it to referance the foreign key OR be null.

Comment: Remove the comma not the reference.

Comment: That's a typo. Its not in the actual table. I'll edit.

Comment: Check the fiddle in my 1st comment. Your code works without an error. Can you reproduce the error in the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use valid referenced value if you are inserting into child table. The ID 2 in table A and ID 5 in table B has to be present.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A 
(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS B   
(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS C 
(
  ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS D 
(
    SID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    DID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SUPP INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (SID, DID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SID) REFERENCES A (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES B (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (SUPP) REFERENCES C (ID)
);

INSERT INTO A VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO D VALUES (2, 5, NULL);
```

Comment: I mentioned that i assume that the tables A and B already contain these values beforehand. And they do, in fact, contain them.